# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.spLogActionsAdd'.'

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

My ASP.NET website is running into this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.spLogActionsAdd'.'

I'm using .NET 4.8, Entity Framework, SQL Server 2022 (v15).

This procedure is working well on the server, so the code doesn't have any problem.

When I try to run it on my local computer I get this error. I checked the connection and the system connects to the correct database for sure.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I would suggest you are *not* connecting to the right database, despite your claim that you are. If you truly *are* connecting to the right instance and database then, as the error tells you, the procedure doesn't exist in that database.

Comment: *"SQL server 2022 (ver. 15)"* SQL Server 2022 is version 16. 2019 is version 15.

Comment: I fail to see how that is related, @NoChance .

Comment: this may provide value: https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper/issues/557 It would help if you use db schema and database name together before the sp name and also to show how you are doing the call.

Comment: @ThomA, good hint.

Comment: @ThomA before I tried to connect other DB, and the data wasn't update. ufter connecting the correct DB the data is correct, but the procedure dosnt found by the system. if I open the  procedure's list in Visual studio - server explorer I see the procedure.

Comment: @ThomA you right, I made mistake with the VS (2022) the SQL  SMS 18

Comment: That error is coming from the SQL Server, so the database you are connected to *does not* have a procedure called `dbo.spLogActionsAdd` on it, @chanak .

Comment: @NoChance I added the schema name before the procedure name - DB.dbo,sp... and it's working now! thank you!!

Comment: Don't do that, just connect to the right database in the first place.

Comment: @Charlieface I tried to connect the right DB, its looks like connect but meybe it doesn't.. the connectionString looks like: ' connectionString="Data Source=MY-PC\MSSQLSERVER01;Initial Catalog=MY-DBi;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework ' and steel did not find the procedure. (only with the solution above). I'm worried if I have to o that for more procedures...

Comment: `Initial Catalog=MY-DB` is that the correct database?

Comment: @Charlieface yes

Answer (score 0):

it is probably because of not using correct name of database or schema before the name of stored procedure or connection string isn't correct.
I suggest you use full of stored procedure with the name of database and schema (if you have one) before your stored procedure name  or review your connection string.